# Why is appsettings.<Environment>.json ignored in dotnet core webapi

Tags: visual-studio-code, asp.net-core-webapi, appsettings

I'm debugging in dotnet core 3.1 webapi project in visual studio code. I do have one `appsettings.json` and one `appsettings.Development.json` in my project that differ in content.

Here's the debug config when hitting F5 inside vs code. This is found in the .vscode/launch.json's "configurations" section

```js
{
    "name": "Launch API",
    "type": "coreclr",
    "request": "launch",
    "preLaunchTask": "build",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/CommercialPaper.API/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/CommercialPaper.API.dll",
    "args": [],
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/CommercialPaper.API",
    "stopAtEntry": false,
    "env": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
    },
    "sourceFileMap": {
        "/Views": "${workspaceFolder}/Views"
    }
}
```

As can be seen, the "Development" env is targeted in debugging mode. Still when inside my code I reference that config, it loads the value from the non-development json file, i.e. the `appsettings.json`.

I even tried to force this behaviour by changing the constructor of my Startup.cs class, but this doesn't work either. I seems I am forced to physically remove the `appsettings.json` to make it work.

```js
        public Startup(IConfiguration config, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
             var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath);

             if (env.IsDevelopment())
             {
                builder.AddJsonFile($"appsettings.Development.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
             }
             else
             {
                builder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
             }

            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this by design?

Cheers